# How can I get slush's scoring code from zone's code to work in clintars code?

Tags: mining-pool-setup

This returns null:

`redisClient.hget(config.coin + ':stats', 'lastBlockFound', function(error, result)`

And is making the score calcuation for each share = 0.

Context:

clintars code is nice because it works with modern nodeJS:https://github.com/clintar/cryptonote-xmr-pool. Zone's code is nice because it has slush's scoring system: https://github.com/zone117x/node-cryptonote-pool . Slush's scoring system prevents pool hopping by weighting recent shares more than old shares.

I tried copying the relevant slush code from zone's and pasting it into clintar's, but it didn't work. Specifically, the score was always equal to 0. I was able to hack the logging function to output the values of various variables, and it turns out the above line was returning null instead of a number, and making the score calculation 0.

here's my lovely repo: https://github.com/Gingeropolous/cryptonote-xmr-pool

Comment: Some more context might help us answer this :)

Comment: more context added.